# UIViewController obj updated in mycustomview controller implementation how to get it in a subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i created a myCustomviewcontroller and made all other .m files as subclasses to it.

and myCustomviewcontroller contains an UIViewController obj and property defined as:

```
@interface MyCustomViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
        UIViewController *topView;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *topView;


@end
```

in the implementation the topview is initialized or given a view controller as in

```
@implementation MyCustomViewController

//some method
    topView = appDelegate.navigationController.topViewController;
@end
```

and there is another class  demo.h which uses MyCustomViewController

```
@interface demo : MyCustomViewController{
}
```

and in the implementation of demo.m i want to get the topview value.
not just the instance of topview but the value which is assigned to topview in the implementation  of MyCustomViewController.m  is this possible if so please help me

thanks.

Comment: normally you could get this by accessing this with super.topView in your demo ViewController

Comment: @JulienKlindt i tried super but it returns a null value.

Comment: did you synthesized the topView in your MyCustomViewController?

Comment: yes i did synthesize it but the same result

Answer (score 0):

By the rule of inheritance you can use the instance variable of base class or super class.
so i will prefer you whenever you use inheritance you initialise the property in derived class not in super class so in your case you initialise

super.topView = appDelegate.navigationController.topViewController;

in demo not in MyCustomViewController.

Comment: you may be right but my question is i want the top view when i am in mycustomviewcontroller once i am in demo.m(derived class) the view changes and its not useful to me.

Comment: When you initialise your demo object then if that method in mycustomviewcontroller called in which you write code for topView assignment then you can access that property with assigned value in demo class later else you will have only instance of topview